# Python Supermarket Checkout program

Tags: python

I have to create a program that asks user to input the number of items to purchase.  the program then asks the user to enter the item and price of each, give a total and provide the amount of change.  I am on the first part.

I have correctly gotten the input of how many items, the item name and cost.  My problem is that for the items subsequent to the first one, it prompts the user for the item price again.

How do I stop this?  I am a beginner and have read and reread the book and I still can not find the answer.  Here is my code:

```
#Checkout program

print "Welcome to the checkout counter! How many items will you be purchasing?"
number = int (raw_input ())

grocerylist = []
costs = []
for i in range(number):
    groceryitem = raw_input ("Please enter the name of product %s:" % (i+1))
    grocerylist.append(groceryitem)
    for i in grocerylist:
        itemcost = raw_input ("How much does %s cost?" % groceryitem)
        costs =[]
        costs.append(itemcost)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you probably want to remove the inner loop:

```
for i in range(number):
    groceryitem = raw_input ("Please enter the name of product %s:" % (i+1))
    grocerylist.append(groceryitem)
    itemcost = raw_input ("How much does %s cost?" % groceryitem)
    costs.append(itemcost)
```

You don't want to loop over every item in the cart every time.  You just want to ask the person for one name and one price on each loop iteration.

Comment: may I ask you another question, BrenBarn/

Comment: @Holly: If you have another question you can ahead and post it on the main site as usual and everyone will be able to take a stab at answering it.